# Array out of bounds exception while doing customised version of insertion sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I trying to solve this [insertion sort problem](http://pastebin.com/2nK5ktJN) (not the exact insertion sort)and wrote the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {

    static void insertionSort(int[] ar,int n) {
        int key=ar[n];
        int temp;
        int j=1;
        for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
              j++;
        }

        for(int i=j-1;i>=0;i--){
            temp=ar[i];
            if(temp>key)
            {
                ar[i+1]=temp;
                printArray(ar);
            }
            else{
                ar[i+1]=key;
                printArray(ar);
            }
        }
    }   

/* Tail starts here */

    static void printArray(int[] ar) {
        for(int n: ar){
            System.out.print(n+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] ar = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            ar[i]=in.nextInt(); 
        }
       insertionSort(ar,n);
    }    
}
```

But I'm getting an error as an array out-of-bound exception, and I could not figure out where it went wrong. The error message is posted below. How should I fix this?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>             at Solution.insertionSort(Solution.java:9)
>             at Solution.main(Solution.java:49)

Comment: The one where he does this: `int key=ar[n];` To the OP, arrays in almost all programming languages are *zero based*. The error is telling you you're trying to access the 6th element in the array, and that array's length is only 5.

Comment: If you use the debugger you'll figure it in no time...

Comment: And once you fix that, you're still going off the end of the array in the second `for` loop in `insertionSort`

Comment: @BrianRoach: you mean to say i should give n-1 as key ?

Comment: @BrianRoach: http://pastebin.com/xRy2CBTg does this make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer as

```
 /* Head ends here */
 import java.util.*;
 public class Solution {

      static void insertionSort(int[] ar,int n) {

          int key=ar[n-1];
          int temp;
          int inserted=0;
          for(int i=ar.length-2;i>-1;i--){
              temp=ar[i];
              if(temp>key)
              {
                  ar[i+1]=temp;
                  printArray(ar);
              }
              else {
                  ar[i+1]=key;
                  inserted=1;
                  break;

              }

          }

          if(inserted==0){
          ar[0]=key;
          }

          printArray(ar);
   }   

   /* Tail starts here */

  static void printArray(int[] ar) {
     for(int n: ar){
        System.out.print(n+" ");
     }
       System.out.println("");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n = in.nextInt();
       int[] ar = new int[n];
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
          ar[i]=in.nextInt(); 
       }
       insertionSort(ar,n);
   }    
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As Brian points out, the first line isn't going to work because you have

```
int key=ar[n];
```

and `n` is `ar.length` (which makes it redundant in this case as well)

---

Using a debugger would show you the error, but I suspect the problem is here

```
ar[i+1]=temp;
```

as i assume `i` is the last valid reference.

BTW

```
      int j=1;
      for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
          j++;

      }
```

is the same as

```
int j = 1 + ar.length;
```

Again, this would make `j` or `j-1` too large to index in the array.

Comment: Nah, it crashes right off the bat. He passes `n` in then tried to access `ar[n]`

Answer (score 2):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException like mentioned above occurs when you try to access a position which doesn't exist.

You have passed your insertSort() function the size of array. I dont think you need a j variable.

by your implementation:

j = ar.length + 1 = n + 1;

For eg:

```
n = 5

ar =  3, 6, 2, 7, 3
      ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
index:0, 1, 2, 3, 4

j = n+1 = 6
```

When you loop your array from i=j-1;

```
temp=ar[i];                     -> ar[5]
ar[i+1]=key; or ar[i+1]=temp;   -> ar[6]
```

both positions that you tried to access above are illegal - hence the error

your for loop should be something like:

```
for(int i=n-2; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but i already found the answer and i'm giving a upvote for you

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, can you name your variables something other than 'i', 'j' and 'n'? 
Then once you have done that, use a consistent style throughout your code (You have dropped some braces and not others?).

Then,..once you can read the code easily, use the debugger, and find out which line you are going our of bounds on. You may find this useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

This is line #49. That means at that point, you try to access a position in the array which does not exist. Your array is of size 'n' currently (name this properly!). You are trying to get position n here:

```
int key=ar[n];
```

The array you have goes from 0 to n-1. For example, if n was 5, you have ar[0], ar[1], ar[2], ar[3] and ar[4]. That is 5 positions, so ar[5] (or ar[n]) does not exist.

Comment: While I agree wholeheartedly, cleaning up style issues are hardly going to fix the problem, and is not really constructive at this point.

Comment: i agree with @Bex , but all you have mentioned is a good one, don't worry i am giving an upvote

Comment: Interesting, but the reasoning behind it was that if the code is neat, and they use the debugger they will find it easier to find the problem themselves. I then pointed to where the problem is, and I was kind of hoping that the OP could work from there. I suppose technically, this doesn't say how to fix the issue but just says what it is and where. However, this looks to me like an assignment and I don't think it helps anyone by saying this is how you fix it, here is the code. I also agree with Peter Lawrey's answer, it explains the issue.